# Magnolia leaves browning and falling

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, pest-control

My Kay Paris Magnolia has browning leaves, which ultimately fall off. I also notice spotting on the leaves. Neighboring trees have a scale problem, but not much on this tree, which I also put white oil on every so often. Any idea of the problem? Below are some photos.

[image: the whole tree]

[image]

[image]

[image]